# What are ways through which i can develop an application which runs on QNX?

Tags: linux, qnx

I was wondering around Internet for proper article regarding how to develop a good UI app for QNX . I was able to find things like -

1. We can use jamaicaVM to port our code developed on java to c .

Following are my questions :

1. On what platform should i develop the app for QNX .
2. The app should have proper UI.

This might even help other developer .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to develop app for QNX from scratch with proper GUI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31957759/how-to-develop-app-for-qnx-from-scratch-with-proper-gui)

Answer (score 0):

You must setup two computers.

1. One computer so called target machine. In this machine you must install operation system Qnx (qnx microkernel, device drivers, filesystems, libraries and etc). Must important think in this machine is **qconn** . It is daemon that support network connection with the **instrumental machine** (please, see 2 item).
2. Second computer so called instrumental machine . In this machine you must install IDE  Qnx Momentics. It is Eclipse based enviroment with gcc, gdb, make and etc. In this computer You will write programms in C or C++ then compile and invoke.

Please, see this http://www.qnx.com/developers/docs/6.4.1/momentics/quickstart/about.html.

Instrumental machine would have any OS with java machine because QNX Momentics is Eclipse based Intergrated Development Enviroment.