# How to develop app for QNX from scratch with proper GUI?

Tags: c, qnx

I was wondering around Internet for proper article regarding how to develop a good UI app for QNX . I was able to find things like -

1. We can use jamaicaVM to port our code developed on java to c .

Following are my questions :

1. On what platform should i develop the app for QNX .
2. The app should have proper UI.

This might even help other beginner .

Comment: As an alternative to QNX, look at the Yocto project: [link](https://www.yoctoproject.org/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now that [Qt 5 has support on QNX 6.6](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/platform-notes-qnx.html), I would suggest using it.  With Qt you can either develop your GUI in either in native C++ (Qt Widgets) or with [Qt Quick](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmlapplications.html).

The biggest limiting factor will be the hardware you are running on (particularly the GPU or lack of) and the available QNX drivers for the hardware.

Answer (score 1):

You might not want to use QT in your QNX app, because it is not supported in QNX 6.5 or lower.
If you want to write a GUI app for QNX 6.5 or lower you should use [photon](http://www.qnx.com/developers/docs/6.4.1/photon/prog_guide/about.html)

Since qnx 6.5 you can't develop your apps inside QNX, though company provides SDK and IDE for developing on windows/linux (not sure about osx). It can be downloaded with SDK from their [official site](http://www.qnx.com/download/group.html?programid=26071) (though it cost some $$ if you are not student).

People normally use virtual machines to develop (I didn't find a way to install QNX 6.6 on a PC, but there are many instructions how to deploy it on any sort of arm mPC)

EDIT: It is worth thinking about making WEB GUI for your app btw.